# AngularJS, component. Непонятки с биндингом

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, компоненты

Пытаюсь разобраться с созданием компонентов в AngularJS, но упёрся в стену.

Есть такой компонент, совсем простой, в образовательных целях.

```
.component('headline', {
       template  : '<div><span class="md-headline">{{$ctrl.fieldValue}}</span></div>',
       controller: function () {},
       bindings  : {
           fieldValue: '<'
       }
   })
```

И, соответственно HTML, где пытаюсь его использовать

```
<headline field-value="Тип"></headline>
```

WebStorm ругается на `"Тип"` так `statement expected. statement expected.`.

Сам ангуляр в консоль ругается так `Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [Т] in expression [Тип].`

Если в биндингах поставить `fieldValue: '@?'`, то все отображается как и задумывалось, без ругани от ангуляра (webstorm продолжает ругаться) и с выводом содержимого `field-value`

Собственно вопросы:

1. Объясните на пальцах, что я делаю не так? Во всех мануалах используют биндинги к свойствам с произвольным содержимым вроде. Подозреваю, что у меня в корне неправильное представление о том, как оно работает.
2. Можно ли сделать компонент, чтобы использовать его таким образом `<headline>Тип</headline>`?

Comment: ну е-мое, передача параметров в директиву: если `@` - строка как есть, если что-то другое - выражение **вычисляется**

Comment: @Grundy дык во всех примерах '<' используют и всякие размышления про одно-двухсторонние связывания. Может ссылку дадите на простое и доступное объяснение, а то у меня уже мозги в трубочку свернулись от погружения в js со товарищи :(

Comment: _The < symbol denotes one-way bindings which are available since 1.5. The difference to = is that the bound properties in the component scope are not watched, which means if you assign a new value to the property in the component scope, it will not update the parent scope._

Comment: по поводу ошибок в Webstorm: проголосуйте. пожалуйста, за https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29774

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как указано в [справке](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component):

> символ `>` указывает на [односторонний](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) биндинг. Его отличие от `=`(двусторонний) заключается в том, что если внутри компонента связанному свойству будет присвоено значение, свойство в родительском скопе обновлено не будет.

Таким образом, это аналог `=`, для которого значение параметра **должно быть *expression***, то есть выражением, которое может разобрать парсер ангуляра.

В случае в вопросе, вероятно из-за наличия не английских символов, парсер кидает ошибку. Если бы символы были английские, ангуляр бы ожидал свойство, которого нет, и вывел бы пустую строку.

Для решения можно просто обрамить кавычками, это покажет парсеру, что передается *строка*:  `<headline field-value="'Тип'"></headline>`

---

Что касается второго вопроса: да, такой синтаксис возможен, для него используется [директива ngTransclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) для указания *куда* вставлять, и свойство `transclude` - для включения.

---

Примеры

```js
angular.module('app', []).component('headline', {
  template: '<div><span class="md-headline">{{$ctrl.fieldValue|| "not set" }}</span></div>',
  controller: function() {},
  bindings: {
    fieldValue: '<'
  }
}).component('headline2', {
  template: '<div><span class="md-headline" ng-transclude></span></div>',
  controller: function() {},
  transclude: true
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <headline field-value="type"></headline>
  <headline field-value="'Тип'"></headline>
  <headline2>Тип 2</headline2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Про первый вопрос.

Вероятно тут дело не в вашем примере, а в версии Angular JS. После версии 1.5 изменения в коде Angular JS для компонентов не отражены в документации (это мое наблюдение).

Итак для передачи данных (объектов и значений) в область видимости компонента необходимо использовать событие `$onChanges(object)` (изменение во входных данных). Более детально можно ознакомиться [здесь](http://www.devcode4.com/article/angularjs-component-bindings) и [здесь](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/angularjs-component-binding-types-my-experiences-10f354d4660).